# Error in ServiceOperation attribute in .Net RIA Service

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I am just trying to learn .Net RIA Service, so i am creating one hello world example. Now in domainserviceclass i am using code below:

```
[ServiceOperation]

public string SayHello()
{
    return "Hello RIA World!";
}
```

It is giving me an error for reference.  I have tried to search on the net but i am unable to identify which namespace I am missing.

I know it is a very small problem but I am unable to find anything on this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the PDC09 drop of RIA services (ie. the beta) ServiceOperation was renamed to Invoke.

There's a document which outlines [Breaking Changes from July CTP to PDC 2009](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=RiaServices&DownloadId=8313)

From that document:

> ServiceOperation renamed to Invoke
>   Convention introduced for Invoke
>   operation
>
> In the PDC bits *ServiceOperation* 
>   has been renamed to *Invoke*:
>   - ServiceOperationAttribute -> InvokeAttribute  i.e.
>   [ServiceOpration] -> [Invoke]
>   - DomainOperation.ServiceOperation -> DomainOperation.Invoke
>
> Also a Convention has been introduced
>   for Invoke operations. Any public
>   method on a Domain Service that is not
>   a [Query], [Insert], [Update],
>   [Delete] or [Custom] method and has
>   only Base Types or collection of Base
>   Types in this signature will be
>   treated as a [Invoke].

The [Invoke attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.domainservices.invokeattribute(VS.91).aspx) lives in the [System.Web.DomainServices namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.domainservices(VS.91).aspx) in System.Web.DomainServices.dll.

Comment: Thanks, can you suggest any good resource for learning RIA services

Comment: Try these:

The Get Started site (http://silverlight.net/getstarted/riaservices/)

The Silverlight.Net Forum for RIA Services ( http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/53.aspx)

Brad Abrams blog (http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/default.aspx) who has a good series of posts on RIA.